# Dynamic Registeration with IOCTLs

Tags: linux, kernel

can we use dynamic registeration for device drivers when IOCTLs are used??

Comment: Could you expand on your question somewhat? how does driver registration relate to IOCTLs?

Comment: When using dynamic device registeration we do not know the major no in advance. while using IOCTLs we define all the IOCTLs in a header file. In the definition of IOCTLs do we not require the majorno. please refer to comments in the the second code chardev.h in the link http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x892.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a major number to define an ioctl, these are unrelated.

What you do need, is a (somewhat) unique (or at least, not one of the built in) number or letter to identify your ioctl range. These may optionally be registered (with the register being in [`Documentation/ioctl/ioctl-number.txt`](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl-number.txt), which also has instructions for usage) to prevent (or at least reduce the probability) of others using it as well.

I highly recommend reading [the documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl-number.txt) in any case as it explains the common conventions and usage.